# A suitable data structure implementation for incrementing values in sparse indices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, data-structures, binary-tree, implementation, sparse-matrix

Currently, I am using cell C which is the size of 1 x H, where H is a very huge number. This cell is mainly used to quickly store and increment some values in very sparse indices in O(1) time. For instance,

```
H = 10000000;
C = cell(1, H);
...
for i = 1:last

    % all values of someIndex(i) are values from 1 to H, unsorted, and contains repeating values.

    C{ someIndex(i) } = C{ someIndex(i) } + someValues(i);

end
...
```

Only a tiny indices in cell C will be used - I see, most of the time, about 1-10% of the whole thing. At first, the implementation is fine for smaller size database, but I am going for bigger database, which H will grow almost exponentially. Therefore, this naive implementation will no longer work.

I was also thinking of something like, instead of using cell, use arrays to store each index and value in this fashion:

Suppose we detect a new index:

```
IndexArray(size(IndexArray, 2) + 1) = someIndex(i);
ValueArray(size(ValueArray, 2) + 1) = someValue(i);
```

Suppose we detect an old index: (sure, we will need to sweep through the whole IndexArray and see whether such old index exist or not)

```
ValueArray( detectOldIndex(i) ) = ValueArray( detectOldIndex(i) ) + someValue(i);
```

However, there is also a problem with this. As more and more indices grow, sweeping through the whole IndexArray will cost more and more time. This is O(N).

Of course, for something like this, we definitely want to go with Trees, however, in Matlab, we don't have a valid Tree structure. I could think of using nested Cells in nested Cells. But the implementation could be quite ugly.

So if I am going to do something like this in Matlab, what are my faster choices?

Comment: Why do you use a cell array, rather than a `sparse` matrix? Are the values not simply scalars?

Comment: On some occasion, I need to store array or strings in this case, so...

Comment: OK, sorry to be unclear about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [`Map container`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html)?

The `Map container` is basically a hash table. Therefore, it should be rather efficient in mapping a small set of "active" indices over a HUGE domain.

Comment: interesting. Do you know the overall efficiency of Map in Matlab? I am talking about time complexity of different Map's operation.

Comment: Unfortunately, my current Matalb's version does not support `Map`s, so I cannot check. I strongly suggest you make a small benchmark and check for yourself.

Comment: I see that Map's performance drops a bit as more and more elements - this is to be expected, of course. The sacrifice for performance in place of memory is worth it. Beside, Map can hold anything, which is what I want. If there are no other answers in a day or two, I will accept this answer.

Comment: @Karl - I'm happy you found my answer worth while. I am curious to find if there is a better solution...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go really big it might be worth using a database. It would have the additional bonus that you don't have to keep the complete data in memory.

[mksqlite](http://mksqlite.berlios.de/) or [mym](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/linkexchange/links/1313-mysql-connector-mym) together with mysql are easy to use.